# PHP PDF Generator: <del> not displayed correctly

Tags: php, css

I'm using a PDF generator to print my invoices in PHP. All works fine but when I include a `<del></del>` to show a deleted price, the deletion line is not centered.

Using `<del>` within the PDF:

[image]

Using `<del>` on the web:

[image]

This is the code:

```
<td>
    <del>69,70&nbsp;€</del> 
    <ins>
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">0,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
    </ins>
</td>
```

Comment: Your code works correct for me. Check your print styles, maybe something impacts the behavior.

Comment: @ladomiryak Hmm I've searched a lot. Maybe a ugly thing I need to life with

Comment: I've found the issue. It a problem in the generator itself. I remove a code snippet and now the del line is shown in the middle. This issue only appears with the "Open Sans" font.